# How can i create a horizontal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I don't want change my view when user rotate the device, and I need the view to be horizontal when it is initialized.

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return NO;
    }
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
        UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 768, 500)];
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self.view addSubview:myView];
    }
```

The problem is the view is not close to left side when the app start. It still have a blank space.
the Frame I set is CGRectMake(0, 150, 768, 500), I don't know the reason.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for certain by your question, but: if you want the view to be in landscape mode, you will want to try the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 768, 500)];
If you're not rotating the view, then the coordinate system is like for the portrait mode.
 try 
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 768, 500)];

Comment: it doesnt worked. (0, 150, 768, 500) have blank scope both at left and top side

Comment: well, then try playing with your CGRectMake coords. Don't see the whole code, so can't help more.